# ¿Cómo obtener el color de mas frecuente en una imagen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Quisiera saber si hay alguna función en python u openCV para poder leer cual es el color que tiene mas proporción en una imagen:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imagen = cv2.imread('album.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

hasta ahora solo llevo esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma pondría ser usando [`numpy.unique()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy-unique) para "contar" la frecuencia de cada color en la imagen. Por ejemplo para obtener los 5 colores más frecuentes:

```
colors, count = np.unique(hsv.reshape(-1, hsv.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
print(colors[np.argsort(-count)][:5])
```

El retorno, `colors` es un array de listas para cada color y en `count` tienes las cantidades de pixeles de dicho color.

Comment: @Patricio Morocho.  El resultado lo devuelve en formato RGB