# Obtener los colores de una imagen

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

Quiero saber que colores tiene una imagen y su cantidad. Es decir que color es el que más aparece y cual menos.

En este mismo foro encontré este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215858/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-el-color-de-mas-frecuente-en-una-imagen) el cual he probado y de entrada me funciona.

Ya que yo uso la siguiente imagen,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y efectivamente el resultado es coherene ya que me saca el BGR de blanco, negro, rojo, azul y verde.

```
[[255 255 255]
 [255   0   0]
 [  0 255   0]
 [  0   0 255]
 [  0   0   0]]
```

He incluso si no me equivoco ordenado de mayor a menor.

Mi problema viene cuando lo inserto en mi programa este código, pues aparentemente solo se trata de sustituir su nombre de la imagen la cual se llamaba *hsv*, por el nombre de la mía.

Mi código:

```
_, threshold_eye = cv2.threshold(ojo, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
threshold_eye = cv2.resize(threshold_eye, None, fx=5, fy=5)
#
colors, count = np.unique(threshold_eye.reshape(-1, threshold_eye.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
print(colors[np.argsort(-count)][:5])
```

Donde ojo es una imagen en blanco y negro,la cual muestro a continuación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto debería aparecer una matriz de la siguiente forma (o al contrario en función de si predomina blanco o negro),

```
[[255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0]]
```

En cambio me aparece,

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0  51 102 153 204 255 255 255 255 255 255 204 153 102  51   0
   51 102 153 204 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 204 153 102
   51   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  51 102 153
  204 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 204 153 102  51   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  20  41  61  82 102
  102 102 102 102 102 132 163 194 224 255 204 153 102  51   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  20  41
   61  82 102 132 163 194 224 255 255 255 255 255 255 204 153 102  51   0
    0   0   0   0   0  51 102 153 204 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 235 214 194 173 153 153 153 153 153 153 122  92  61  31   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  31  61  92 122 153
  153 153 153 153 153 173 194 214 235 255 204 153 102  51   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  31  61
   92 122 153 173 194 214 235 255 255 255 255 255 255 204 153 102  51   0
    0   0   0   0   0  51 102 153 204 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 224 194 163 132 102 102 102 102 102 102  82  61  41  20   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  41  82 122 163 204
  204 204 204 204 204 214 224 234 245 255 204 153 102  51   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  41  82
  122 163 204 214 224 234 245 255 255 255 255 255 255 204 153 102  51   0
    0   0   0   0   0  51 102 153 204 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 214 173 133  92  51  51  51  51  51  51  41  31  20  10   0   0   0]]
```

¿Que hago mal? ¿Hay otras maneras de saber el color de una imagen?

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: Sospecho que tu "ojo" está almacenado en escala de grises, es decir, que cada pixel tiene una única componente. Por ejemplo, un pixel blanco tendría el valor 255, en lugar de (255,255,255) como tú supones. Y probablemente el código que pones está diseñado para imágenes con tres componentes por pixel.  Prueba a convertirlo con `cv2.cvtColor(imagen_grises,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`

Comment: Totalmente correcto, he de pensar mejor como atacar este tema. ¡Gracias! @abulafia

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es obtener el histograma de la imagen. La librería numpy obtiene el histograma de un vector con la función np.histogram().

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

file = r'C:\Users\w10\Pictures\ojo.png'
#El valor cero es para leer la imagen en escala de grises
img = cv2.imread(file,0)
#img.flatten vuelve a la imagen un vector de (n*m)
hist,bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])
plt.plot(hist)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La variable hist, es un vector de 256. El índice corresponde al valor del pixel (0-255) y el valor hist[i] corresponde al número de pixeles encontrados en la imagen.

En este caso, hist[0] y hist[255] corresponden a negro y blanco respectivamente, que son los valores más altos en el vector.